# Improper integral defined by the Cauchy integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The Cauchy integral operator is defined to be $$
\mathcal{C}f(z)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt
$$
Now one can define the positive Cauchy integral operator as $$
\mathcal{C}_+f(a)=lim_{b\to+0}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t-(a+ib)}dt
$$

My question is, under what conditions would $\mathcal{C}_+$ be properly defined, and how is it defined? To be more precisely, if $f\in L^2$, then why is the improper integral well defined, and does the "=" mean the $L^2$ sense? How can one see this?